# JavaScript - Is there a way to get the offsetTop of an element after hypothetical CSS styles are applied?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a way to get the value of an element's `offsetTop` after some CSS styles are applied without actually applying that CSS?

For example, if an element's CSS currently is:

```
position: absolute;
top: 45px;
```

Is there a way to know what the `offsetTop` of that element would be for:

`top: auto;`

without actually applying `top: auto;`?

If we do actually apply it, even for a short time, it causes a flicker.

Comment: You do this in a hidden element (but not a display: none element) and calculate. This will avoid flicker I guess.

Comment: Excellent, that works beautifully!  Please answer for credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple trick for this:

Render the element but keep it invisible (using `opacity: 0` or `visibility: hidden` or position it outside the viewport) and calculate its dimensions using JavaScript. This way you will avoid FOUC issues.